# I have a mysql query which is taking a lot of time for approx 10.4 millinon records. it is taking a lot of time

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

```
SELECT ticker.ticker_id,
       ticker.ticker_code,
       inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history.close AS previousDayClose
FROM inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history.candle_price_history_id) AS candle_price_history_id
   FROM inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history
   WHERE inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history.close>0
   GROUP BY inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history.ticker_id) derivedTable 
   ON inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history.candle_price_history_id = derivedTable.candle_price_history_id
RIGHT JOIN ticker ON ticker.ticker_id = inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history.ticker_id
WHERE ticker.is_active = 1
```

Kindly suggest me any other  technique, I can apply here to reduce the time.

this is the table structure

```
Field                    Type           Null    Key     Default  Extra           
-----------------------  -------------  ------  ------  -------  ----------------
candle_price_history_id  int(8)         NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  
ticker_id                bigint(11)     NO      MUL     (NULL)                   
candle_interval          int(11)        YES             1                        
trade_date               datetime       YES             (NULL)                   
trade_price              decimal(16,2)  YES             (NULL)                   
trade_size               decimal(30,2)  YES             (NULL)                   
open                     decimal(16,2)  YES             (NULL)                   
high                     decimal(16,2)  YES             (NULL)                   
low                      decimal(16,2)  YES             (NULL)                   
close                    decimal(16,2)  YES             (NULL)                   
volume                   bigint(30)     YES             (NULL)                   
creation_date            datetime       YES             (NULL)                   
is_ebabled               bit(1)         YES             b'1'
```

Comment: kindly suggest me any other alternative to optimize this query.

Comment: Add to the question the structure of your tables (including all indexes that you have)

Comment: Dekel means use the MySQL command `SHOW CREATE TABLE [your_table]` this way we have the tables and indexes.. you should also include the output of `EXPLAIN [your_query]`

Comment: I am new to sql, so don't know much about these.

Comment: How long does this query take and does it (eventually) return the correct result?

Comment: Post here the table structure + `explain` command for the SQL

Comment: Rather than saying: "Here is my query. Guess what it does and then optimize it." you should say what your tables contain and what the query is supposed to do.

Comment: 99 trillion dollars is excessive.  Penny stocks need more than 2 decimals.

Comment: `INT UNSIGNED` is inadequate for the busiest ticker, but virtually all other settings are excessive.  Saving space will help with speed.

Comment: Please rewrite the query with short (1-letter) aliases; the current query seems to be more than 50% table names.

Answer (score 1):

It would look more natural to select from the ticker table first, then find the latest history entry and then join that:

```
SELECT 
  t.ticker_id,
  t.ticker_code,
  h.close  AS previousDayClose 
FROM ticker t
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT ticker_id, MAX(candle_price_history_id) AS candle_price_history_id
  FROM inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history
  WHERE close > 0
  GROUP BY ticker_id
) m on m.ticker_id = t.ticker_id
LEFT JOIN inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history h 
  ON h.candle_price_history_id = m.candle_price_history_id
WHERE t.is_active = 1;
```

However, your query should also work.

Make sure to have appropriate indexes. I'd suggest:

```
create index idx_ticker on ticker(is_active, 
                                  ticker_id, 
                                  ticker_code);
```

and

```
create index idx_history on inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history(ticker_id,
                                                                  close,
                                                                  candle_price_history_id);
```

or

```
create index idx_history on inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history(close,
                                                                  ticker_id,
                                                                  candle_price_history_id);
```

(The order of columns may make a difference, so you may want to try both versions for the history index. Well, you can of course create both indexes at the same time with different names and see which one gets used.)

Comment: Really? Exactly the three indexes I mentioned? I'd be surprised, but if you say so ...

Comment: And the query is still running slow? How much time does it take? How many records are returned?

Comment: And please try the third trigger, too. As said, the order of columns in the index can make a big difference.

Comment: wokays,thank you kettner. I will try, can you please send me some docs for performance tuning in mysql on manishymca19@gmail.com.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot recommend any docs or tutorials, as I don't work with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Generally creating the apropiate indexes would speed up your querys with multiples filtering conditions.

For instance, creating an index on *ticker_id* may be the key to make the query faster.

On the other hand, creating indexes on *close* and *is_active* could help, but only if *is_active = 1* its up to like 10% or less, of the records in the table.

Also, you could change the MAX function for an *ORDER BY candle_price_history_id DESC LIMIT 1* as the table is already ordered by *candle_price_history_id*

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In ticker table ticker_id is primary key so we need not to create index on ticker_id. Suggest me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes. That is true, but only if table _inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history_, the field ticker_id is a Foreing Key of that field in the table _ticker_. If not, then you should create that index. Please check it and let me know. Cheers.

Comment: yes, it is the foreign key in the inter_day_ticker_candle_history. can you send me some docs for performance tuning in mysql.

Comment: Could you edit your post to add the complete create statement of both tables? Maybe seeing the full data structure we could come up with something better :)

Comment: Execute the following: `show create table ticker;` and `show create table inter_day_ticker_candle_price_history;`. That should return all the info needed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a "groupwise max" problem.  For optimization techniques for that pattern, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max .

See my comments on shrinking the table size.  I assume this could be a huge table, possibly bigger than will fit in RAM?

If this is InnoDB, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` needs to be about 70% of available RAM.

If `(ticker_id, tradedate)` is unique, then make it the `PRIMARY KEY` and get rid of `id` completely.  The order is important -- this clusters all the rows for a given ticker together, thereby cutting down on I/O.  (*If* you are currently I/O-bound, this *may* give you a 10-fold speedup.)

Provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  You need for the query (as written) to *start* with the derived query.  `LEFT JOIN` will not allow that.

Consider getting rid of inactive rows and rows with close <= 0.

Comment: We can't make any change in the table structure so please suggest other way.